# Wrap Core Bluetooth Callbacks to Async/Wait

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, swift-concurrency

I would like to convert the concept of Core-Bluetooth's methods with callbacks into methods that use async/wait to make my code more readable.

eg: Reading a characteristic requires

- Read: `peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)`
- Handle the response in  `public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)`

I'd like to have something like: `func read(for characteristic: CBCharacteristic) async throws -> [UInt8]` and this tried using `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` to implements this

So for reading I use

```
let (_, char) = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ (continuation: ReadValueCheckedContinuation) in
   self.readContinuation = continuation
   peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
})
```

In the callback I have

```
// in case of success
r.resume(returning: (peripheral, characteristic))
```

This works fine for single reads. If I run multiple reads in a sequence, the reads don't wait for the result of the previous callbacks, which causes trouble. Any suggestion on how to synchronize this?

Comment: You need an AsyncStream

Comment: I replaced the implement using AsyncStream; for BLE I need to only keep one element in the stream and then move on. But still, the issue is the same.

Comment: We can’t help you troubleshoot what we can see.

Comment: Synchronization would only happen if your "multiple reads" are coming from the same task calling your `try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation` code multiple times.  You haven't provided any code to show how the. "multiple reads" are conducted.